# Variable doesn't take on the default value on create: result is "can't be blank" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My migration file contains:

```
t.belongs_to :user,      index: true
t.belongs_to :organization, index: true
t.boolean :member,       default: false, null: false
t.boolean :admin,        default: false, null: false
t.boolean :moderator,    default: false, null: false
```

The model file includes:

```
validates :member, presence: true
validates :admin, presence: true
validates :moderator, presence: true
```

In my seeds file I `create` a new record:

```
user.relationships.create!(organization_id: 2, member: true, moderator: true)
```

This fails with the error `Admin can't be blank` and indeed if I add `admin: false` to the seeds line, the error is gone. But I would expect that when I don't specify the value for `admin`, it would take on its default value from the migration file. Why is its behaviour different from my expectation? Am I doing something wrong or is my expectation incorrect so that I always need to specify values for variables that are not allowed to be nil?

Comment: you donot need to add validation when you are already doing default: false at db level.

Comment: this is the same issue you as reported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506575/rails-database-defaults-and-model-validation-for-boolean-fields. try to add this `validates :admin, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}` rather than presence.

Comment: Thanks @Athar. That indeed worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validates` instruction checks if the attribute is present at creation time (and it isn't as you don't specify it in the parameters of `create`).

Removing `validates :admin, presence: true` leads to applying the default value (`false`) when `admin` is not specified.