# Rails validation failing with create in controller.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a record if none exists.

```
@construction = Construction.create!(:bom_created => false,
                                    :recipe_created => false,
                                    :cost_rollup_complete => false,
                                    :opportunity_id => $current_opportunity)
```

bom_created, recipe_created and cost_rollup_complete are mandatory fields per my model.

```
validates_presence_of :bom_created
validates_presence_of :recipe_created
validates_presence_of :cost_rollup_complete
```

I thought I was Ok with passing the values as part of the create but I am getting

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ConstructionsController#show
Validation failed: Bom created can't be blank, Recipe created can't be blank, Cost rollup complete can't be blank

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/constructions_controller.rb:76:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: are your fields boolean? if so then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10506648/1536309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validates_presence_of` will return invalid for `false`. (`false.present? => false`)

You should instead use

```
validates_inclusion_of :bom_created, in: [true, false]
validates_inclusion_of :recipe_created, in: [true, false]
validates_inclusion_of :cost_rollup_complete, in: [true, false]
```

Comment: In rails, `present?` is defined as `!blank?` its the same thing. Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F

Answer (score 3):

> If you want to validate the presence of a **boolean field** (where the real values are true and false), you will want to use `validates_inclusion_of` :field_name, in: [true, false].

change your validations to

```
validates_inclusion_of :bom_created,          in: [true, false]
validates_inclusion_of :recipe_created,       in: [true, false]
validates_inclusion_of :cost_rollup_complete, in: [true, false]
```

[source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000083)